# How to find columns with integer values in dataframe and add quotes around all the integer or float values in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to first check which columns have numeric values (int or float) and then add double quotes(" ") around the values. Is there any way to dynamically check for such columns, as the column name or location is not known initially.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io

data='''
a,s,d,f
5.33,on,off,500
6.10,on,off,800
'''
df= pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data))
```

Expected output: 
df

```
       a   s    d    f
0  "5.33"  on  off  "500"
1  "6.10"  on  off  "800"
```

**Update:**

I got the column names using df.dtypes and checked for non-object datatypes. Now I just want to add quotes to those columns dynamically.

```
non_obj_datatypes = df.columns[df.dtypes != 'object']

non_obj_datatypes
Out[4]: Index(['a', 'f'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better approach that the other answer is to limit processing to just
these columns, which need it, i.e. **numeric** columns.

First find columns of interest:

```
myCols = df.select_dtypes(exclude='object').columns
```

Then substitute new values, changing at the same time their type:

```
df[myCols] = df[myCols].apply(lambda col: '"' + col.astype(str) + '""')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for col in df.columns:
    try:
        df[col].astype(float)
        df[col] = df[col].astype(str).apply(lambda x : '"%s"' % x)
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(df)
```

**output**

```
        a   s    d      f
0  "5.33"  on  off  "500"
1   "6.1"  on  off  "800"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numbers
df.applymap(lambda x: f'"{x}"' if isinstance(x, numbers.Number) else x)
```

Result

```
        a   s    d      f
0  "5.33"  on  off  "500"
1   "6.1"  on  off  "800"
```

As opposed to the other answers, this also works for mixed type columns:

```
df.iloc[0,0]='x'
df.applymap(lambda x: f'"{x}"' if isinstance(x, numbers.Number) else x)
#       a   s    d      f
#0      x  on  off  "500"
#1  "6.1"  on  off  "800"
```